# Multiple framework dependencies matching [UWP]

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, dependencies, .net-native

I have an issue with debugging my UWP application. In debug bug mode there is error but in release mode. I have this error and couldn't find any solution.

Any advice? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What's your VS version? In which scenario you get this exception, for example, you changed anything? Only with an exception we could not help you. Could you please provide more information? How I reproduce your issue on my side?

Comment: @SunteenWu-MSFT Hello, you are right. I'm sorry, forgot to add information about environment. I use VS2017 Professional. I only changed Nuget package references (from package.json to packageReference) and updated VS2017 to latest version. That's all I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. It was **".net native shared library"** version difference in **".nuget.targets"** file. I updated all of them to same version and error disappeared. Thanks for assisting.